# How is my fragment's onCreateView called before it's onCreate when finishing the activity in onCreate?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity, ondestroy

This is very odd. I have a simple app which once logged in shows a fragment in an activity. The app also has an inactivity "timeout" after which time it finishes the activity and shows the login screen -- if the app is in the background when the timeout occurs then when the next `onCreate` or `onStart` event occurs in the activity it is finished.

However sometimes when returning to the logged in activity I get a NPE in the onActivityCreated method of my fragment. The fragment is very simple and simply calls a method on a String. The string itself is retrieved through a call to getArguments(). I have verified that whenever the Fragment is created the arguments are always set.

So it seems somehow the `onActivityCreated` is actually called before `onCreate` in the fragment, which I know should be impossible. Below is a portion of the stack trace:

```
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at com.example.app.fragment.MyFragment.onActivityCreated(MyFragment.java:203)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1070)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop(FragmentManager.java:1888)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:787)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:764)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:322)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onDestroy(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:261)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at com.example.app.MyActivity.onDestroy(MyActivity.java:195)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5273)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1110)
01-14 15:34:37.176: E/AndroidRuntime(3272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3562)
```

Comment: can you should the source code?

Answer (score 3):

After some more debugging I have discovered the exception occurs because of a use of `getActivity()` before `onActivityCreated()` is called -- moreover a method is called on `getActivity()` and the method relies upon the activity having been created. /idiot

Comment: Do you know what method you were calling that relied on the activity being created?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are storing the string in such a way that it is not saved when the fragment goes into the background?  Without code that's the only guess I can offer.

One way to fix your problem would be to simply do a null check in your `onActivityCreated` method.  Depends on how you want to handle it though.