# android: why FragmentActivity.onDestroy call the fragment onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments

the crash is below

```
    at com.activity.upgrade.VersionFragment.parse(VersionFragment.java:73)
at com.activity.upgrade.VersionFragment.onCreateView(VersionFragment.java:57)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchReallyStop(FragmentManager.java:1956)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:790)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.doReallyStop(FragmentActivity.java:767)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:314)
at com.common.BaseActivity.onDestroy(BaseActivity.java:107)
at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5421)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1117)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3494)
```

It is strange that fragment onCreatView is not invoked from Activity onCreate but from onDestroy. This case happens when entering the app after system or some 3rd party tools kill the app. Anyone met this before?

**********UPDATE**********

From the source code, it seems related the Fragment state. Its state is Fragment.INITIALIZING or Fragment.CREATED state when FragmentActivity in its onDestroy. I think it should be in the wrong state.

Comment: Hi, I got same crash, did you make it?

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866854/why-is-dialogfragment-oncreateview-called-when-activity-is-being-destroyed)

the stacktrace is ok, the problem maybe in onDestroy or onResume callback. You should awlways can super.onResume or super.OnDestroy in your onResume method!

Google app demo also figout life cycle call must be first call in subclass's method.[image]

Comment: Yes, I already followed the rule, calling super.xxx before anything, such as onPause, onDestroy. Still met this problem :(